# Concurrency And Locking Across Load Balanced Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, concurrency, locking

I am writing an application where users can create items with a start date and an end date and save them to a SQL database hosted in Microsoft Sql Server. The rule in the application is that only a single item can be active for a given time (no overlapping items). The application also needs to be load balanced, which means (as far as I know) traditional semaphores / locking won't work.

A few additional items:

- The records are persisted into two tables (based on a business requirement).
- Users are allowed to "insert" records in the middle of an existing record. Inserted records adjust the start & end dates of any pre-existing records to prevent overlapping items (if necessary).
- Optimally we want to accomplish this using our ORM and .Net. We don't have as much leeway to make database schema changes but we can create transactions and do other kinds of SQL operations through our ORM.

Our goal is to prevent the following from happening:

- Saves from multiple users resulting in overlapping items in either table (ex. users 1 & 2 query the database, see that there aren't overlapping records, and save at the same time)
- Saves from multiple users resulting in a different state in each of the destination tables (ex. Two users "insert" records, and the action is interleaved between the two tables. Table A looks as though User 1 went first, and table B looks as though User 2 went first.)

My question is how could I lock or prevent multiple users from saving / inserting at the same time across load balanced servers.

Note: We are currently looking into using sp_getapplock as it seems like it would do what we want, if you have experience with this or feel like it would be a bad decision and want to elaborate that would be appreciated as well!

Edit: added additional info

Comment: What do you mean by *Microsoft SQL* ? Are you talking about Microsoft **SQL Server** - the fully relational db mgmt system - or are you talking about Microsoft **Access** with SQL - the file-based database "system" that is also from Microsoft and also speaks SQL :... you're not clear on that - please make it clearer for us!

Comment: Sorry, Microsoft Sql Server!

Comment: `sp_getapplock` in a transaction is as good as it looks.  Much simpler than relying on row/page locking to implement this kind of application logic.  But you _also_ want to have DRI or triggers actually enforce these rules.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple of options:

- You can create a stored procedure which wraps the INSERT operation in a transaction:

  ```
  begin tran
      select to see if there is an existing record
      you can:
          - invalidate the previous record
          - insert a new record
      or
          - raise an error
      commit tran
  catch error
      rollback tran
  ```
- You can employ a last-in-wins strategy where you don't employ a write level lock, but rather a read-level pseuodo-lock, essentially ignoring all records except the latest one.